# Changing slider image on thumbnail. Image changes for a second then reverts

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm new to coding and have an assignment where we need to code a slider without jquery plugins. Currently, my slider works, but the final function, clicking a thumbnail to change slider image is not working well.

The image changes correctly and stays for a second, before reverting to the first image. I would like to prevent the image reverting but can't pinpoint the problem. The assignment's front end can be accessed here: http://stepworks.shoukochan.com/

Any advice will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Javascript: Each of the 4 slider images has a number variable of 1 to 4. Clicking the left or right arrow on the slider adds or subtract 1 from the variable.

```
function photo(x) {
var image = document.getElementById('image');
imageCount = imageCount + x;
    if(imageCount > 100 && imageCount <200){
imageCount = 1;
}       else if (imageCount > 200 && imageCount <300){
imageCount = 2;
}        else if (imageCount > 300 && imageCount <400){
imageCount = 3;
}        else if (imageCount > 400 && imageCount <500){
imageCount = 4;
}   else if (imageCount > 4){
imageCount = 1;
}   else if (imageCount < 1){
imageCount = 4;
}

image.src = "img/img"+ imageCount +".jpg";
}
```

Html: Each of the 4 images are thumbnails. On click, a large number will be set to the variable. Depending on the number, the appropriate image variable will be set accordingly.

```
<section class="photos">
        <ul>
            <li class="one_photo"><a href=""><img OnClick="photo(150)" src="img/1_thumb.jpg" alt="description of photo 1" /></a></li>
            <li class="one_photo"><a href=""><img OnClick="photo(250)" src="img/2_thumb.jpg" alt="description of photo 2" /></a></li>
            <li class="one_photo"><a href=""><img OnClick="photo(350)" src="img/3_thumb.jpg" alt="description of photo 3" /></a></li>
            <li class="one_photo"><a href=""><img OnClick="photo(450)" src="img/4_thumb.jpg" alt="description of photo 4" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be your conditions that are a problem, why not just do a simple switch statement?
Something like this may help:

```
switch(x) {    
    case 150:
       imageCount = 1;
       break;    
    case 250:
       imageCount = 2;
       break;    
    case 350:
       imageCount = 3;
       break;    
    case 450:
       imageCount = 4;
       break;    
    default:
       imageCount = 1;
       break; 
}
```